# Replace all occurrences of all chars within a string with another chars without interfering one with eachother

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption

I started learning some cryptography from a book and now I have an exercise that wants me to find out the frequencies of each character from a string:

Something like this:

```
import collections

my_coded_string = """NTCGPDOPANFLHJINTOOFITOVJHJCTMMHIHEMTCPFDWTSOFSHTOGFWTE
TTJJTBTOOFSZOVEOCHCVCHPJHOCGTOHNQMTOCNTCGPDCGFCSTQMFBTO
FBGFSFBCTSHJCGTQMFHJCTYCXHCGFAHYTDDHAATSTJCBGFSFBCTSHJC
GTBHQGTSCTYCCGHONTCGPDQSTOTSWTOCGTMTCCTSASTRVTJBZHJCGTQ
MFHJCTYCFJDOPPJTBFJOTFSBGAPSCGTQMFHJCTYCASPNFIHWTJBHQGT
SCTYCEZBPNQFSHJICGTASTRVTJBZPATFBGMTCCTSFIFHJOCCGTLJPXJ
BPNNPJASTRVTJBZHJCGTVJDTSMZHJIMFJIVFIT"""

letters = collections.defaultdict(float)
for letter in my_coded_string:
    letters[letter] += 1

d_descending = OrderedDict(sorted(letters.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True))
print d_descending
```

This will return a dictionary of type `float` with all the keys and their frequencies (in decreased order). So far so good, nothing scary.

**Output:**

```
([
    ('T', 57.0), ('C', 40.0), ('J', 29.0), ('F', 27.0), ('H', 26.0), ('S', 23.0), ('G', 22.0), ('O', 20.0), ('B', 16.0), 
    ('P', 15.0), ('M', 12.0), ('A', 10.0), ('N', 10.0), ('I', 9.0), ('Q', 9.0), ('D', 8.0), ('V', 8.0), ('Y', 6.0), 
    ('Z', 6.0), ('E', 4.0), ('W', 4.0), ('R', 3.0), ('L', 2.0), ('X', 2.0)
])
```

Now, they say that in order to decode this string I have to compare these frequencies, with the ones they provide, which seems to be the expected frequency of each character in the English language.

[image]

Now, the problem that I have is: how can I replace all occurences of letter `T` which is most frequent, with letter `E` which is the first frequent letter of English alphabet, then `C` with `T` and so on ?

At some point, when I'll replace `T` with `E` I will have 57 `E`s but I will also have the remaining `e`s. Any ideas ?

Comment: Iterate over the string and process one character at a time.

Comment: As I explained, if I do this, I will replace first ocurence of `T` with `E` for example and so on until the end. But at some point, I'll have to also process the `E` letter and this will overwrite the first transformation. How will I handle this ?

Comment: No, I mean iterate over `my_coded_string` - something like `decoded_string = ''.join([process(char) for char in my_coded_string])` (if this is unfamiliar look up *"list comprehension"*) - then each character is replaced exactly once and you don't get overwriting.

Comment: I'm familliar with list comprehension. Can you put this as an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also create an `OrderedDict` for your mapping of expected english
language (decreasing order), you will be able create a
second `dict` that can be used to translate `my_coded_string` in one
iteration.

Let's say the expected english mapping is called `freqs`:

```py
translate_table = dict(zip(d_descending, freqs))
my_string = ''.join([translate_table[c] for c in my_coded_string])
```

Assuming you'll also want to handle *newlines* (`\n`), here's a full working code:

```py
import collections
import itertools

freqs = collections.OrderedDict([
    ('e', 12.702), ('t', 9.056), ('a', 8.167), ('o', 7.507),
    ('i', 6.749), ('n', 6.749), ('s', 6.327), ('h', 6.094),
    ('r', 5.987), ('d', 4.253), ('l', 4.052), ('c', 2.782),
    ('u', 2.758), ('m', 2.406), ('w', 2.360), ('f', 2.228),
    ('g', 2.015), ('y', 1.974), ('p', 1.929), ('b', 1.492),
    ('v', 0.978), ('k', 0.772), ('j', 0.153), ('x', 0.150),
    ('q', 0.095), ('z', 0.074)])

my_coded_string = """NTCGPDOPANFLHJINTOOFITOVJHJCTMMHIHEMTCPFDWTSOFSHTOGFWTE
TTJJTBTOOFSZOVEOCHCVCHPJHOCGTOHNQMTOCNTCGPDCGFCSTQMFBTO
FBGFSFBCTSHJCGTQMFHJCTYCXHCGFAHYTDDHAATSTJCBGFSFBCTSHJC
GTBHQGTSCTYCCGHONTCGPDQSTOTSWTOCGTMTCCTSASTRVTJBZHJCGTQ
MFHJCTYCFJDOPPJTBFJOTFSBGAPSCGTQMFHJCTYCASPNFIHWTJBHQGT
SCTYCEZBPNQFSHJICGTASTRVTJBZPATFBGMTCCTSFIFHJOCCGTLJPXJ
BPNNPJASTRVTJBZHJCGTVJDTSMZHJIMFJIVFIT"""

def translate(coded):
    coded_lines = coded.split('\n')
    letters = collections.defaultdict(float)
    for letter in itertools.chain(*coded_lines):
        letters[letter] += 1

    mapping = dict(zip(
        (i[0] for i in sorted(letters.items(),
                              key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True)),
        freqs.keys()))

    return '\n'.join(''.join(mapping[letter] for letter in line)
                     for line in coded_lines)

print(translate(my_coded_string))
```